# Connecting to RethinkDB with C# freezes

Tags: c#, .net, rethinkdb

Hello i am trying to connect to a RethinkDB database using the C# driver and it seems it just wont connect.It does not move on to the next line:

```
RethinkDB r = new RethinkDB();
Connection con=await r.Connection().Hostname("localhost").Port(9300).ConnectAsync();
--code after this line
```

Comment: Could you please change your asynchronous call to a synchronous, in order we verify that you would connect to the database ? Just remove the `await` and replace `ConnectAsync` with `Connect`. If you don't make it to connect, then the problem would not be in your code but something goes wrong with the database. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the port to 28015.I was using the same port as the UI for rehthink.